# Dynamic cursor in inner loop. Multiple cursors

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor

Consider the following.

```
declare

v_name     person.name%TYPE;
v_surname  person.surname%TYPE;

cursor department_cursor is
    select * from department;

cursor person_cursor is 
    select * from person 
    where nvl(name, '')   = nvl(v_name, '');    

begin
  open department_cursor;  
  open person_cursor;
  for department_row in department_cursor loop

    v_name  := department_row.name;
    v_surname  := department_row.surname;

    for person_row in person_cursor loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I got here:'||person_row.p_id);
    end loop;   

  end loop;
  close person_cursor;
  close department_cursor;
end;
/
```

Don't try to understand what it does. It's just a stripped/vandalized version of the actual code.
The juice though remains. What I want to do, is have two cursors. The second cursor is dynamic and it depends on the rows that the first cursor returns.

The above results in `ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have lines which read

```
open department_cursor;  
open person_cursor;
```

and later you have other lines which read

```
for department_row in department_cursor loop
```

and

```
for person_row in person_cursor loop
```

The later lines are attempting to open cursors which are already open.

I suggest you rewrite your code as:

```
declare
  v_name     person.name%TYPE;
  v_surname  person.surname%TYPE;

  cursor department_cursor is
    select * from department;

  cursor person_cursor is 
    select * from person 
    where nvl(name, '')   = nvl(v_name, '');    
begin
  for department_row in department_cursor loop
    v_name  := department_row.name;
    v_surname  := department_row.surname;

    for person_row in person_cursor loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I got here:'||person_row.p_id);
    end loop;   
  end loop;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I didn't know that this syntax opens the cursor too. Thank you. It worked. I will mark it in too mins.